# LINQ Group By with IF statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a page which can be accessed by users with multiple roles.  The roles are:

i) town
ii) district
iii) country

If a user has the role 'Town', then he is associated with a town e.g. Los Angeles.  If a user has the role 'District', then he is associated with a district e.g. California.  If a user has the role 'Country', then he is associated with a country e.g. USA.

Now I know that Los Angeles is not a town but a city and that California is not a district but a state.  I only gave these examples to help you understand the structure of the data.

Each role can view a number of documents.  A document is related to a section e.g. Finances, Infrastructure etc.

Now, I have an SP which gets the entire data from the database.  Then I want to use LINQ to group the data.  I want to do something like this:

```
GROUP BY Role
             --> GROUP BY Section
                                --> GROUP BY Document
                                                   --> IF ROLE is Town --> GROUP BY Town (e.g. Los Angeles)
                                                   --> IF ROLE is District --> GROUP BY District (e.g. California)
                                                   --> IF ROLE is Country --> GROUP BY Country (e.g. USA)
```

Is the last part containing the if statement possible using LINQ?  If yes, can you please give me a brief example of the syntax?  I am working using query syntax.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you not fetch the data in three separate queries? It would make things much simpler.

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet as well. Just write 3 queries then union the result.

Comment: Thank you, both JonSkeet and kayson.  Coming to think of it, I think that is the best approach.  Out of curiosity, is it possible to do the last part containing the if statement in LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with class(town, country and state) that inherits from Role

```
public enum typeRoleEnum
{
   country = 0,
   state = 1,
   town = 2
}

public class Role {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public typeRoleEnum type { get; set; }
}
public class Town: Role {}
public class District : Role { }
public class Country : Role { }
```

name in Role is a property that is common for each class and that contain the name of state, town or country. Only on property like this you will by group by.

than you create a list of object like this

```
List<Role> list = new List<Role>();

Role rol1 = new Town() { name = "Town1", type = typeRoleEnum.town  }; 
Role rol2 = new Town() { name = "Town2", type = typeRoleEnum.town  };
Role rol3 = new Town() { name = "Town2", type = typeRoleEnum.town  };

list.Add(rol1);
list.Add(rol2);
list.Add(rol3);
```

Here you must known wich type list you're creating
the query will be

```
var t = from l in list
    group l by l.name into grp
select grp.Key;
```

probably in this case you have one query but the if statement is in other position of your code, when you must create the list

can you use only a class with role type? that probably is a better solution unless the three class must have different behavior and you want only group by on common properties